# Progress Bar not working in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I have a simple Progress Bar where IsIndeterminate="True". It's working fine in WP7 but not in WP8. All I see is one dot that doesn't scroll. I've read how the Progress Bar was included in a Toolkit which I should've used in WP7 for performance issues which I didn't (ooops) but running the app in WP8 shows just 1 dot on the screen. I've upgraded the project to WP8 as apparently the Progress Bar within the SDK is the best one to use yet I still have the problem. My xaml is as follows:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

Here is an image showing which reference package the Progress Bar is using from the Toolbox:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=93AA9A941DD84E76!3185&authkey=!AJOdQz3YPV8xEtY&v=3

Could I possibly be referencing a package that has an older implementation of the Progress Bar?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproduction of this. Just do file new WP8 project and drop a ProgressBar in the middle of the page. Does that reproduce the problem?

Comment: The Progress bar you are using seem the right one (and i have used it previously and work) so that's probably  something else in you xaml which hide it (for example is the progress bar added at the end of the xaml so that it show on top?). The one from the toolkit is the one which not working in windows phone 8.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I created a new WP8 project and the progress bar worked. I also created a new page with no other elements (so there's no possibility of something hiding it) in my current project and the progress bar didn't work. So there's something in my project that is stopping it from working. Any thoughts what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because I had my own copy of CustomThemeResources which had a WP7 definition of ProgressBar. I removed it and it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, saved me a lot of time!